# Determine if a List contains elements from another List

Tags: c#

I have an object model `MyObject` that contains a list of long called `ObjectList`. I have another list called `TestList` that also contains longs and I want to determine if `TheObject.ObjectList` contains any elements that are in `TestList`.

I'm trying with something like this but it's not giving Count as an option.

```
if (TheObject.ObjectList.Any(TestList).Count() > 0) {...}
```

How should I rewrite this?
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
TheObject.ObjectList.Intersect(TestList).Any()
```

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

Note: There are also [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) and [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358229.aspx) set opeartions.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if ( TheObject.ObjectList.Intersect(TestList).Any() ) 
 { 
   ... 
 }
```